# Updating code to include wait.until conditions

Tags: java, selenium

I've been using a page object model to find elements and perform actions on them e.g.

```
public class loginPage extends HelperClass
{

@FindBy(xpath = ("//button[@type='submit']"))
private WebElement loginButton;

public loginPage clickLogin()
{
    loginButton.click()
    return this;
}
}
```

From within my JUnit test I'd call the function thus:

```
WebDriver driver = setUpBrowser("FireFox", websiteURL);
loginPage LoginPage = new loginPage(driver);
delay(5000); //delay 5 seconds
LoginPage.clickLogin();
```

You will have noticed the explicit delay which is not ideal. So I decided to write a wait method like this:

```
public void waitForElementAndClick(WebElement element, WebDriver driver)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or
            (
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element), ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element) 
            ));
    System.out.println(element);

    element.click();
}
```

All works well so what is the problem you ask? Well the problem is it is a huge maintenance effort to go and change all the code I've written to accommodate this  wait feature. I'll need to change the JUnit calls to include the driver e.g.

```
LoginPage.clickLogin(driver);
```

Then in the page object model I'll have to change all the methods as well e.g.

```
public loginPage clickLogin(WebDriver driver)
{
    waitForElementAndClick(loginButton, driver);
    return this;
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing this without having to go through all the code applying these changes?

Answer (score 0):

public void waitForElementAndClick(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) : Why does this function require a WebDriver object explicitly ?

1) if the wait function is written inside loginPage class, which already has a webdriver constructor argument, the same object can be passed inside the wait function

```
public class loginPage extends HelperClass
{
WebDriver driver;
//Constructor : 
public loginPage(WebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
 }
}
```

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); : here, the driver variable will be automatically taken

2) If the wait function is written in some other class, the same method can be followed to avoid having a driver variable for wait function

Answer (score 0):

See [Extend Selenium WebDriver WebElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642348/extend-selenium-webdriver-webelement)